# Why was my question about a specific chord progression flagged?

Tags: discussion, support

I posted [a question about how to improvise over a specific progression](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/50739/major-blues-jazz-improve-over-a-i-iii-vi-iv-progression), and it was immediately flagged as inappropriate for the SE. Yet here are at least 4 questions that are almost identical in spirit to mine that weren't flagged and received multiple responses:

[How to improvise over a C#, B, A chord progression?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/27398/how-to-improvise-over-a-c-b-a-chord-progression?rq=1)

[soloing over I-IV-V blues progression (E-A-B)](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/25080/soloing-over-i-iv-v-blues-progression-e-a-b?rq=1)

[Major Blues Scale over I-IV-V progression](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/20677/major-blues-scale-over-i-iv-v-progression?rq=1)

[I-IV-V blues progression](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/16103/i-iv-v-blues-progression?rq=1)

Why was my question singled out? How is it different from any of these?

The moderator who shut it down claims that it was because I was asking for references as opposed to direct advice, so I edited it accordingly but it is still on hold.

In the philosophy SE where I usually hang out, moderators don't immediately shut down questions, they at least offer advice on how to change it to suit the SE's guidelines, and the option to vote on reopening the question is available, especially after editing by the OP.

Moreover reference requests are a completely acceptable type of question in a lot of other SE's (you can't get more objective than "here's an author/reference/link to what you are asking for"), why are they considered so inappropriate here?

Answer (score 6):

The questions you have highlighted here are very different to your original question, as we discussed at length in chat. Your edit is good, and if you had pinged me in chat to let me know, I would have opened it hours ago, rather than finding this Meta post later when I checked through my usual evening flag routine. It is open now.

Putting a post on hold so that it can be edited is absolutely what was needed here. If it had been left open in its original form it would have attracted answers of the form "here is a link to a good one:" and that would not be suitable here. Questions asking for a link to something are off topic on most SE sites (there are some exceptions)

Comment: If you would have opened it hours ago, why couldn't/wouldn't another mod? There seems to be discepancy (a little) between ideals. Not for the first time! Draconian is far too strong a term!

Comment: Tim - any mod could have, there is no discrepancy. the key was notifying. That's not draconian - that's just mods having lives outside SE too. We are much more relaxed about posts than many other sites - this is probably my second most chilled out site in this regard. On some, posts like this one would have been hammered and downvoted into oblivion - by the community, not even by mods.